# Open Media Vault DHCP IP not showing on Router's connected devices

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, openmediavault

I've currently got a media server set up and working on my local network. It's running openmediavault.

It connects to the network correctly and can be accesed from any other machine on the network using SMB/CIFS in OMV. It's IPv4 method is set to DHCP.

However, I cannot see it's IP in the list of connected devices in my routers control panel. Does this mean that the router isn't assigning the OMV server it's IP? I can only see it's current IP by running `ping myservershostname`. If not, how else could it be assigned an IP?

I'd like for my router to assign the IP via DHCP so as I can reserve it an IP and have it connect with the same IP forever. This would make accessing it from the browser a lot easier as I could bookmark it and not have to ping it every time.